# Severe performance degredation over time in multi-threading: what am I missing?

Tags: multithreading, rust

In my application a method runs quickly once started but begins to continuously degrade in performance upon nearing completion, this seems to be even irrelevant of the amount of work (the number of iterations of a function each thread has to perform). Once it reaches near the end it slows to an incredibly slow pace compared to earlier (worth noting this is not just a result of fewer threads remaining incomplete, it seems even each thread slows down).

I cannot figure out why this occurs, so I'm asking. What am I doing wrong?

---

#### An overview of CPU usage:

*A slideshow of the problem*

Worth noting that CPU temperature remains low throughout.

This stage varies with however much work is set, more work produces a better appearance with all threads constantly near 100%. Still, at this moment this appears good.

[image]

Here we see the continued performance of earlier,

[image]

Here we see it start to degrade. I do not know why this occurs.

[image]

After some period of chaos most of the threads have finished their work and the remaining threads continue, at this point although it seems they are at 100% they in actually perform their remaining workload very slowly. I cannot understand why this occurs.

[image]

---

#### Printing progress

I have written a multi-threaded [`random_search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_search) ([documentation link](https://docs.rs/simple_optimization/0.9.0/simple_optimization/fn.random_search.html)) function for optimization. Most of the complexity in this function comes from printing data passing data between threads, this supports giving outputs showing progress like:

```
2300
 565 (24.57%) 00:00:11 / 00:00:47 [25.600657363049734] { [563.0ns, 561.3ms, 125.0ns, 110.0ns] [2.0µs, 361.8ms, 374.0ns, 405.0ns] [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] }
```

I have been trying to use this output to figure out whats gone wrong, but I have no idea.

This output describes:

- The total number of iterations `2300`.
- The total number of current iterations `565`.
- The time running `00:00:11` (`mm:ss:ms`).
- The estimated time remaining `00:00:47` (`mm:ss:ms`).
- The current best value `[25.600657363049734]`.
- The most recently measured times between execution positions (effectively time taken for thread to go from some line, to another line (defined specifically with `update_execution_position` in code below) `[563.0ns, 561.3ms, 125.0ns, 110.0ns]`.
- The averages times between execution positions (this is average across entire runtime rather than since last measured) `[2.0µs, 361.8ms, 374.0ns, 405.0ns]`.
- The execution positions of threads (`0` is when a thread is completed, rest represent a thread having hit some line, which triggered this setting, but yet to hit next line which changes it, effectively being between 2 positions) `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

---

#### The `random_search` code:

Given I have tested implementations with the other methods in my library [`grid_search`](https://docs.rs/simple_optimization/0.9.0/simple_optimization/fn.grid_search.html) and [`simulated_annealing`](https://docs.rs/simple_optimization/0.9.0/simple_optimization/fn.simulated_annealing.html) it would suggest to me the problem does not atleast entirely reside in `random_search.rs`.

`random_search.rs`:

```rust
pub fn random_search<
    A: 'static + Send + Sync,
    T: 'static + Copy + Send + Sync + Default + SampleUniform + PartialOrd,
    const N: usize,
>(
    // Generics
    ranges: [Range<T>; N],
    f: fn(&[T; N], Option<Arc<A>>) -> f64,
    evaluation_data: Option<Arc<A>>,
    polling: Option<Polling>,
    // Specifics
    iterations: u64,
) -> [T; N] {
    // Gets cpu data
    let cpus = num_cpus::get() as u64;
    let search_cpus = cpus - 1; // 1 cpu is used for polling, this one.

    let remainder = iterations % search_cpus;
    let per = iterations / search_cpus;

    let ranges_arc = Arc::new(ranges);

    let (best_value, best_params) = search(
        // Generics
        ranges_arc.clone(),
        f,
        evaluation_data.clone(),
        // Since we are doing this on the same thread, we don't need to use these
        Arc::new(AtomicU64::new(Default::default())),
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(Default::default())),
        Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false)),
        Arc::new(AtomicU8::new(0)),
        Arc::new([
            Mutex::new((Duration::new(0, 0), 0)),
            Mutex::new((Duration::new(0, 0), 0)),
            Mutex::new((Duration::new(0, 0), 0)),
            Mutex::new((Duration::new(0, 0), 0)),
        ]),
        // Specifics
        remainder,
    );

    let thread_exit = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
    // (handles,(counters,thread_bests))
    let (handles, links): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = (0..search_cpus)
        .map(|_| {
            let ranges_clone = ranges_arc.clone();
            let counter = Arc::new(AtomicU64::new(0));
            let thread_best = Arc::new(Mutex::new(f64::MAX));
            let thread_execution_position = Arc::new(AtomicU8::new(0));
            let thread_execution_time = Arc::new([
                Mutex::new((Duration::new(0, 0), 0)),
                Mutex::new((Duration::new(0, 0), 0)),
                Mutex::new((Duration::new(0, 0), 0)),
                Mutex::new((Duration::new(0, 0), 0)),
            ]);

            let counter_clone = counter.clone();
            let thread_best_clone = thread_best.clone();
            let thread_exit_clone = thread_exit.clone();
            let evaluation_data_clone = evaluation_data.clone();
            let thread_execution_position_clone = thread_execution_position.clone();
            let thread_execution_time_clone = thread_execution_time.clone();
            (
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    search(
                        // Generics
                        ranges_clone,
                        f,
                        evaluation_data_clone,
                        counter_clone,
                        thread_best_clone,
                        thread_exit_clone,
                        thread_execution_position_clone,
                        thread_execution_time_clone,
                        // Specifics
                        per,
                    )
                }),
                (
                    counter,
                    (
                        thread_best,
                        (thread_execution_position, thread_execution_time),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        })
        .unzip();
    let (counters, links): (Vec<Arc<AtomicU64>>, Vec<_>) = links.into_iter().unzip();
    let (thread_bests, links): (Vec<Arc<Mutex<f64>>>, Vec<_>) = links.into_iter().unzip();
    let (thread_execution_positions, thread_execution_times) = links.into_iter().unzip();

    if let Some(poll_data) = polling {
        poll(
            poll_data,
            counters,
            remainder,
            iterations,
            thread_bests,
            thread_exit,
            thread_execution_positions,
            thread_execution_times,
        );
    }

    let joins: Vec<_> = handles.into_iter().map(|h| h.join().unwrap()).collect();

    let (_, best_params) = joins
        .into_iter()
        .fold((best_value, best_params), |(bv, bp), (v, p)| {
            if v < bv {
                (v, p)
            } else {
                (bv, bp)
            }
        });

    return best_params;

    fn search<
        A: 'static + Send + Sync,
        T: 'static + Copy + Send + Sync + Default + SampleUniform + PartialOrd,
        const N: usize,
    >(
        // Generics
        ranges: Arc<[Range<T>; N]>,
        f: fn(&[T; N], Option<Arc<A>>) -> f64,
        evaluation_data: Option<Arc<A>>,
        counter: Arc<AtomicU64>,
        best: Arc<Mutex<f64>>,
        thread_exit: Arc<AtomicBool>,
        thread_execution_position: Arc<AtomicU8>,
        thread_execution_times: Arc<[Mutex<(Duration, u64)>; 4]>,
        // Specifics
        iterations: u64,
    ) -> (f64, [T; N]) {
        let mut execution_position_timer = Instant::now();
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        let mut params = [Default::default(); N];

        let mut best_value = f64::MAX;
        let mut best_params = [Default::default(); N];
        for _ in 0..iterations {
            // Gen random values
            for (range, param) in ranges.iter().zip(params.iter_mut()) {
                *param = rng.gen_range(range.clone());
            }

            // Update execution position
            execution_position_timer = update_execution_position(
                1,
                execution_position_timer,
                &thread_execution_position,
                &thread_execution_times,
            );

            // Run function
            let new_value = f(&params, evaluation_data.clone());

            // Update execution position
            execution_position_timer = update_execution_position(
                2,
                execution_position_timer,
                &thread_execution_position,
                &thread_execution_times,
            );

            // Check best
            if new_value < best_value {
                best_value = new_value;
                best_params = params;
                *best.lock().unwrap() = best_value;
            }

            // Update execution position
            execution_position_timer = update_execution_position(
                3,
                execution_position_timer,
                &thread_execution_position,
                &thread_execution_times,
            );

            counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);

            // Update execution position
            execution_position_timer = update_execution_position(
                4,
                execution_position_timer,
                &thread_execution_position,
                &thread_execution_times,
            );

            if thread_exit.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // Update execution position
        // 0 represents ended state
        thread_execution_position.store(0, Ordering::SeqCst);
        return (best_value, best_params);
    }
}
```

`util.rs`:

```rust
pub fn update_execution_position<const N: usize>(
    i: usize,
    execution_position_timer: Instant,
    thread_execution_position: &Arc<AtomicU8>,
    thread_execution_times: &Arc<[Mutex<(Duration, u64)>; N]>,
) -> Instant {
    {
        let mut data = thread_execution_times[i - 1].lock().unwrap();
        data.0 += execution_position_timer.elapsed();
        data.1 += 1;
    }
    thread_execution_position.store(i as u8, Ordering::SeqCst);
    Instant::now()
}

pub struct Polling {
    pub poll_rate: u64,
    pub printing: bool,
    pub early_exit_minimum: Option<f64>,
    pub thread_execution_reporting: bool,
}
impl Polling {
    const DEFAULT_POLL_RATE: u64 = 10;
    pub fn new(printing: bool, early_exit_minimum: Option<f64>) -> Self {
        Self {
            poll_rate: Polling::DEFAULT_POLL_RATE,
            printing,
            early_exit_minimum,
            thread_execution_reporting: false,
        }
    }
}

pub fn poll<const N: usize>(
    data: Polling,
    // Current count of each thread.
    counters: Vec<Arc<AtomicU64>>,
    offset: u64,
    // Final total iterations.
    iterations: u64,
    // Best values of each thread.
    thread_bests: Vec<Arc<Mutex<f64>>>,
    // Early exit switch.
    thread_exit: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    // Current positions of execution of each thread.
    thread_execution_positions: Vec<Arc<AtomicU8>>,
    // Current average times between execution positions for each thread
    thread_execution_times: Vec<Arc<[Mutex<(Duration, u64)>; N]>>,
) {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut stdout = stdout();
    let mut count = offset
        + counters
            .iter()
            .map(|c| c.load(Ordering::SeqCst))
            .sum::<u64>();

    if data.printing {
        println!("{:20}", iterations);
    }

    let mut poll_time = Instant::now();
    let mut held_best: f64 = f64::MAX;

    let mut held_average_execution_times: [(Duration, u64); N] =
        vec![(Duration::new(0, 0), 0); N].try_into().unwrap();
    let mut held_recent_execution_times: [Duration; N] =
        vec![Duration::new(0, 0); N].try_into().unwrap();
    while count < iterations {
        if data.printing {
            // loop {
            let percent = count as f32 / iterations as f32;

            // If count == 0, give 00... for remaining time as placeholder
            let remaining_time_estimate = if count == 0 {
                Duration::new(0, 0)
            } else {
                start.elapsed().div_f32(percent)
            };
            print!(
                "\r{:20} ({:.2}%) {} / {} [{}] {}\t",
                count,
                100. * percent,
                print_duration(start.elapsed(), 0..3),
                print_duration(remaining_time_estimate, 0..3),
                if held_best == f64::MAX {
                    String::from("?")
                } else {
                    format!("{}", held_best)
                },
                if data.thread_execution_reporting {
                    let (average_execution_times, recent_execution_times): (
                        Vec<String>,
                        Vec<String>,
                    ) = (0..thread_execution_times[0].len())
                        .map(|i| {
                            let (mut sum, mut num) = (Duration::new(0, 0), 0);
                            for n in 0..thread_execution_times.len() {
                                {
                                    let mut data = thread_execution_times[n][i].lock().unwrap();
                                    sum += data.0;
                                    held_average_execution_times[i].0 += data.0;
                                    num += data.1;
                                    held_average_execution_times[i].1 += data.1;
                                    *data = (Duration::new(0, 0), 0);
                                }
                            }
                            if num > 0 {
                                held_recent_execution_times[i] = sum.div_f64(num as f64);
                            }
                            (
                                if held_average_execution_times[i].1 > 0 {
                                    format!(
                                        "{:.1?}",
                                        held_average_execution_times[i]
                                            .0
                                            .div_f64(held_average_execution_times[i].1 as f64)
                                    )
                                } else {
                                    String::from("?")
                                },
                                if held_recent_execution_times[i] > Duration::new(0, 0) {
                                    format!("{:.1?}", held_recent_execution_times[i])
                                } else {
                                    String::from("?")
                                },
                            )
                        })
                        .unzip();

                    let execution_positions: Vec<u8> = thread_execution_positions
                        .iter()
                        .map(|pos| pos.load(Ordering::SeqCst))
                        .collect();
                    format!(
                        "{{ [{}] [{}] {:.?} }}",
                        recent_execution_times.join(", "),
                        average_execution_times.join(", "),
                        execution_positions
                    )
                } else {
                    String::from("")
                }
            );
            stdout.flush().unwrap();
        }

        // Updates best and does early exiting
        match (data.early_exit_minimum, data.printing) {
            (Some(early_exit), true) => {
                for thread_best in thread_bests.iter() {
                    let thread_best_temp = *thread_best.lock().unwrap();
                    if thread_best_temp < held_best {
                        held_best = thread_best_temp;
                        if thread_best_temp <= early_exit {
                            thread_exit.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
                            println!();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            (None, true) => {
                for thread_best in thread_bests.iter() {
                    let thread_best_temp = *thread_best.lock().unwrap();
                    if thread_best_temp < held_best {
                        held_best = thread_best_temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            (Some(early_exit), false) => {
                for thread_best in thread_bests.iter() {
                    if *thread_best.lock().unwrap() <= early_exit {
                        thread_exit.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            (None, false) => {}
        }

        thread::sleep(saturating_sub(
            Duration::from_millis(data.poll_rate),
            poll_time.elapsed(),
        ));
        poll_time = Instant::now();

        count = offset
            + counters
                .iter()
                .map(|c| c.load(Ordering::SeqCst))
                .sum::<u64>();
    }

    if data.printing {
        println!(
            "\r{:20} (100.00%) {} / {} [{}] {}\t",
            count,
            print_duration(start.elapsed(), 0..3),
            print_duration(start.elapsed(), 0..3),
            held_best,
            if data.thread_execution_reporting {
                let (average_execution_times, recent_execution_times): (Vec<String>, Vec<String>) =
                    (0..thread_execution_times[0].len())
                        .map(|i| {
                            let (mut sum, mut num) = (Duration::new(0, 0), 0);
                            for n in 0..thread_execution_times.len() {
                                {
                                    let mut data = thread_execution_times[n][i].lock().unwrap();
                                    sum += data.0;
                                    held_average_execution_times[i].0 += data.0;
                                    num += data.1;
                                    held_average_execution_times[i].1 += data.1;
                                    *data = (Duration::new(0, 0), 0);
                                }
                            }
                            if num > 0 {
                                held_recent_execution_times[i] = sum.div_f64(num as f64);
                            }
                            (
                                if held_average_execution_times[i].1 > 0 {
                                    format!(
                                        "{:.1?}",
                                        held_average_execution_times[i]
                                            .0
                                            .div_f64(held_average_execution_times[i].1 as f64)
                                    )
                                } else {
                                    String::from("?")
                                },
                                if held_recent_execution_times[i] > Duration::new(0, 0) {
                                    format!("{:.1?}", held_recent_execution_times[i])
                                } else {
                                    String::from("?")
                                },
                            )
                        })
                        .unzip();

                let execution_positions: Vec<u8> = thread_execution_positions
                    .iter()
                    .map(|pos| pos.load(Ordering::SeqCst))
                    .collect();
                format!(
                    "{{ [{}] [{}] {:.?} }}",
                    recent_execution_times.join(", "),
                    average_execution_times.join(", "),
                    execution_positions
                )
            } else {
                String::from("")
            }
        );
        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
}
// Since `Duration::saturating_sub` is unstable this is an alternative.
fn saturating_sub(a: Duration, b: Duration) -> Duration {
    if let Some(dur) = a.checked_sub(b) {
        dur
    } else {
        Duration::new(0, 0)
    }
}
```

---

#### `main.rs`

```rust
use std::{cmp,sync::Arc};

type Image = Vec<Vec<Pixel>>;
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Pixel {
    pub luma: u8,
}
impl From<&u8> for Pixel {
    fn from(x: &u8) -> Pixel {
        Pixel { luma: *x }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Setup
    // -------------------------------------------

    fn open_image(path: &str) -> Image {
        let example = image::open(path).unwrap().to_rgb8();
        let dims = example.dimensions();
        let size = (dims.0 as usize, dims.1 as usize);
        let example_vec = example.into_raw();

        // Binarizes image
        let img_vec = from_raw(&example_vec, size);
        img_vec
    }

    println!("Started ...");
    let example: Image = open_image("example.jpg");
    let target: Image = open_image("target.jpg");
    // let first_image = Some(Arc::new((examples[0].clone(), targets[0].clone())));
    println!("Opened...");
    let image = Some(Arc::new((example, target)));

    // Running the optimization
    // -------------------------------------------
    println!("Started opt...");
    let best = simple_optimization::random_search(
        [0..255, 0..255, 0..255, 1..255, 1..255],
        eval_one,
        image,
        Some(simple_optimization::Polling {
            poll_rate: 100,
            printing: true,
            early_exit_minimum: None,
            thread_execution_reporting: true,
        }),
        2300,
    );

    println!("{:.?}", best); // [34, 220, 43, 253, 168]
    assert!(false);

    fn eval_one(arr: &[u8; 5], opt: Option<Arc<(Image, Image)>>) -> f64 {
        let bin_params = (
            arr[0] as u8,
            arr[1] as u8,
            arr[2] as u8,
            arr[3] as usize,
            arr[4] as usize,
        );
        let arc = opt.unwrap();
        // Gets average mean-squared-error
        let binary_pixels = binarize_buffer(arc.0.clone(), bin_params);
        mse(binary_pixels, &arc.1)
    }

    // Mean-squared-error
    fn mse(prediction: Image, target: &Image) -> f64 {
        let n = target.len() * target[0].len();
        prediction
            .iter()
            .flatten()
            .zip(target.iter().flatten())
            .map(|(p, t)| difference(p, t).powf(2.))
            .sum::<f64>()
            / (2. * n as f64)
    }
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    fn difference(p: &Pixel, t: &Pixel) -> f64 {
        p.luma as f64 - t.luma as f64
    }
}

pub fn from_raw(raw: &[u8], (_i_size, j_size): (usize, usize)) -> Vec<Vec<Pixel>> {
    (0..raw.len())
        .step_by(j_size)
        .map(|index| {
            raw[index..index + j_size]
                .iter()
                .map(Pixel::from)
                .collect::<Vec<Pixel>>()
        })
        .collect()
}

pub fn binarize_buffer(
    mut img: Vec<Vec<Pixel>>,
    (_, _, local_luma_boundary, local_field_reach, local_field_size): (u8, u8, u8, usize, usize),
) -> Vec<Vec<Pixel>> {
    let (i_size, j_size) = (img.len(), img[0].len());
    let i_chunks = (i_size as f32 / local_field_size as f32).ceil() as usize;
    let j_chunks = (j_size as f32 / local_field_size as f32).ceil() as usize;

    let mut local_luma: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![vec![u8::default(); j_chunks]; i_chunks];

    // Gets average luma in local fields
    // O((s+r)^2*(n/s)*(m/s)) : s = local field size, r = local field reach
    for (i_chunk, i) in (0..i_size).step_by(local_field_size).enumerate() {
        let i_range = zero_checked_sub(i, local_field_reach)
            ..cmp::min(i + local_field_size + local_field_reach, i_size);
        let i_range_length = i_range.end - i_range.start;
        for (j_chunk, j) in (0..j_size).step_by(local_field_size).enumerate() {
            let j_range = zero_checked_sub(j, local_field_reach)
                ..cmp::min(j + local_field_size + local_field_reach, j_size);
            let j_range_length = j_range.end - j_range.start;

            let total: u32 = i_range
                .clone()
                .map(|i_range_indx| {
                    img[i_range_indx][j_range.clone()]
                        .iter()
                        .map(|p| p.luma as u32)
                        .sum::<u32>()
                })
                .sum();

            local_luma[i_chunk][j_chunk] = (total / (i_range_length * j_range_length) as u32) as u8;
        }
    }

    // Apply binarization
    // O(nm)
    for i in 0..i_size {
        let i_group: usize = i / local_field_size; // == floor(i as f32 / local_field_size as f32) as usize
        for j in 0..j_size {
            let j_group: usize = j / local_field_size;

            // Local average boundaries
            // --------------------------------
            if let Some(local) = local_luma[i_group][j_group].checked_sub(local_luma_boundary) {
                if img[i][j].luma < local {
                    img[i][j].luma = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if let Some(local) = local_luma[i_group][j_group].checked_add(local_luma_boundary) {
                if img[i][j].luma > local {
                    img[i][j].luma = 255;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // White is the negative (false/0) colour in our binarization, thus this is our else case
            img[i][j].luma = 255;
        }
    }
    img
}

#[rustfmt::skip]
fn zero_checked_sub(a: usize, b: usize) -> usize { if a > b { a - b } else { 0 } }
```

---

[Project zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-meF2WAuQcHboxMwQlwWs4Jcss85K1HT/view?usp=sharing) (in case you'd rather not spend time setting it up).

Else, here are the images being used as `/target.jpg` and `/example.jpg` (it shouldn't matter it being specifically these images, any should work):

[image]
[image]

And `Cargo.toml` dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.4"
itertools = "0.10.1" # izip!
num_cpus = "1.13.0" # Multi-threading
print_duration = "1.0.0" # Printing progress
num = "0.4.0" # Generics
rand_distr = "0.4.1" # Normal distribution
image = "0.23.14"
serde = { version="1.0.118", features=["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.50"
```

---

I do feel rather reluctant to post such a large question and
inevitably require people to read a few hundred lines (especially given the project doesn't work in a playground), but I'm really lost here and can see no other way to communicate the whole area of the problem. Apologies for this.

As noted, I have tried for a while to figure out what is happening here, but I have come up short, any help would be really appreciate.

Comment: have you tried running it under `perf stat` or `perf record`?

Comment: You can pause the execution of the program in the debugger and check what those threads are doing ;)

Comment: Can you check the CPU temperature and frequencies during the run? Frequencies can be seen in `/proc/cpuinfo`, for temps you can use the command `sensors` for example. Would be best to write a little script (or use some program) to log those values over time. Might be that your CPU is just reaching some thermal limit or so.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Have checked CPU temperature, it remains low throughout the run (will add that to question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some basic debugging (aka `println!` everywhere) shows that your performance problem is not related to the multithreading at all. It just happens randomly, and when there are 24 threads doing their job, the fact that one is randomly stalling is not noticeable, but when there is only one or two threads left, they stand out as slow.

But where is this performance bottleneck? Well, you are stating it yourself in the code: in `binary_buffer` you say:

```
    // Gets average luma in local fields
    // O((s+r)^2*(n/s)*(m/s)) : s = local field size, r = local field reach
```

The values of `s` and `r` seem to be random values between `0` and `255`, while `n` is the length of a image row, in bytes `3984 * 3 = 11952`, and `m` is the number of rows `2271`.

Now, most of the times that `O()` is around a few millions, quite manageable. But if `s` happens to be small and `r` big, such as `(3, 200)` then the number of computations blows up to over `1e11`!

Fortunately I think you can define the ranges of those values in the original call to `random_search` so a bit of tweaking there should send you back to reasonable complexity. Changing the ranges to:

```
[0..255, 0..255, 0..255, 1..255, 20..255],
//                               ^ here
```

seems to do the trick for me.

PS: These lines at the beginning of `binary_buffer` were key to discover this:

```
    let o = (i_size / local_field_size) * (j_size / local_field_size) * (local_field_size + local_field_reach).pow(2);
    println!("\nO() = {}", o);
```

Comment: Seems I was looking past the simple solution here. Thank you.